# Creating a generic interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0

I know that the title may be confusing (or even misleading), but I'm planning to create an interface which is generic, and it should implement a method involving a generic parameter.

When implemented in class `AFirst`, it should have a method `MyMethod<A>()` that returns the type A, and when implemented in class `BFirst`, it should have a method `MyMethod<B>()` that returns type B. I need this functionality as there is an inheritance relationship between A and B (and MANY others) and I need a generic method that I can call with any of the base classes.

If it was confusing, have a look at what I want to do:

Consider B derives from A.
Consider AFirst and BFirst implement `IMyInterface<A>` and `IMyInterface<B>` respectively:

```
BFirst mySecondObj = new BFirst();
A myA = BFirst.MyMethod<A>();
B myB = BFirst.MyMethod<B>();
```

I need access to the `MyMethod` templates for the base classes to, so when I instantiate the `BFirst` instance, I can call either `MyMethod` for `A` or `B`. I'm building a template system and think these `AFirst` and `BFirst` are the templates, and `MyMethod` acts like a factory method. I will have a big hierarchy, and the project needs to be extensible by deriving even more classes from my base class `A`, so I can't just create seperate interfaces or methods for each of them.

I tried this:

```
interface IMyInterface<T> where T : A
{
    T GetNewInstance<T>();
}
```

and I tried to implement this way, but I'm getting it as created like this when I click implement:

```
class AFirst : IMyInterface<A>
{
    public T GetNewInstance<T>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Didn't make sense to me in the way that I've specified the T type to be `A`, but it still implements as T. For example, it will go like this (below is how I want it to happen)

```
class AFirst : IMyInterface<A>
{
    public A GetNewInstance<A>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class BFirst : AFirst, IMyInterface<B>
{
    public B GetNewInstance<B>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and from outer code, call the sample as in the beginning of my question:

```
BFirst myBFirst = new BFirst();
A a = BFirst.GetNewInstance<A>(); //calls AFirst's method and returns A
B b = BFirst.GetNewInstance<B>(); //calls BFirst's method and returns B
```

How is this possible?
Thanks,
Can.

Comment: There's nothing misleading about the title... "generic interface" is what we all call an interface with a generic type parameter :)

Comment: thanks, i just wanted to be sure :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your generic interface you define a generic method. I think that's where the confusion is. It should be a normal method that returns your generic type. I.e.

```
interface IMyInterface<T> where T : A
{
    T GetNewInstance();
}
```

This will get implemented as

```
class AFirst : IMyInterface<A>
{
    public A GetNewInstance()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

which I'm guessing is what you want.

Comment: this will work for A. but as I said, I've got BFirst too, of which the same method should return an instance of B. but, from this derived class B, I also need to be able to access the GetNewInstance method of FirstA too, which will return A. and no, I won't be doing type casting, I need exactly what I stated in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly over complicating this. You could consider a [Template pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx). The base class is abstract and defines an overridable method. Classes inheriting from this base class then provide implementations of this method.

You can still use generics and an interface but this pattern is probably the basis you would need to start from.

**Edit:**

```
public abstract class ABase<T>
{
    public abstract T MyMethod();
}

public class A : ABase<A>
{
    public override A MyMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class B : A
{
}
```

And to implement an interface, this would be

```
public interface IHasMethod<T>
{
    T MyMethod();
}

public abstract class ABase<T> : IHasMethod<T> ...
```

Comment: What if he needs an interface?

Comment: Like I suggest, he can still use an interface. You can still use an interface with the Template pattern. In this case it would be the same as suggested by Tim. I have edited my post to show this.

Comment: i'm not really sure how to implement this for my situation